# How do I use jQuery to slide transition to a new page?

Tags: jquery, slide, transition

I am trying to do the same thing as this site: http://touchtech.co.nz/#!/

If you click on their navigation menu, it slides to a new page (it's not just an image slider, it's actually taking you to a new page).

Is their a plugin for this, or does anyone know how to go about this?

Best,
Alex

p.s. I know you can do it using the jquery mobile framework, but I would prefer not to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a SPA (Single Page Application). All the views are preloaded. The changes that you see in your URL are the result of jQuery library like `sammy.js` or `history.js`. I don't know which platform you are using for software development, but if it is ASP.NET MVC then check http://www.asp.net/single-page-application to get the idea how it works.